Package @azure/openai@2.0.0-beta.2 missing data_sources parameter for client.chat.completions.create call
I'm trying to query AzureOpenAI for chat completions, with on my own data (Azure Search), from TypeScript code.
I use packages @azure/openai@2.0.0-beta.2 and openai@4.62.1.
I followed the instructions from https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/openai/openai/MIGRATION.md#azure-on-your-data
import "@azure/openai/types"; is properly declared:

The code is as in the documentation:
const response = await client.chat.completions.create({
  model: '',
  messages,
  data_sources: [
    {
      type: "azure_search",
      parameters: {
        endpoint: "XXXX",
        index_name: "YYYY",
        authentication: {
          type: "system_assigned_managed_identity",
        },
      },
    },
  ]
});


End yet, parameter data_sourceis not recognized.
The error reads: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data_sources' does not exist in type 'ChatCompletionCreateParamsBase'

What am I missing here?
I uninstalled and re-installed both packages openai and @azure/openai, I tried different sets of parameters on client.chat.completions.create, read and re-read the documentation: nothing makes the data_sources parameter available...

I tried out your code snippets and specify package version. seems working fine in my end.

"dependencies": {
"@azure/openai": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
"openai": "^4.62.1"
}


import { AzureOpenAI } from "openai";
import "@azure/openai/types";

const deployment = "gpt-4o";
const apiVersion = "2024-08-01-preview";
const apiKey = "xxxxx";
const endpoint = "https://xxxxx.openai.azure.com"; // Add your endpoint here
const options = { deployment, apiVersion, apiKey, endpoint }
const client = new AzureOpenAI(options);

const messages = [
    { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
    { role: "user", content: "Tell me a joke." }
  ];

const response = await client.chat.completions.create({
    model: '',
    messages,
    data_sources: [
      {
        type: "azure_search",
        parameters: {
          endpoint: "XXXX",
          index_name: "YYYY",
          authentication: {
            type: "system_assigned_managed_identity",
          },
        },
      },
    ]
  });
  



